# Including Layout Problem in express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Have you any Idea what's wrong here? When I run a view file in a single page Its run fine but when I add external layout in this template its generate an error. What do you think what is the problem in this code?

```
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine(
    expressHbs({
      extname: "hbs",
      defaultLayout: "main-layouts",
      layoutsDir: "views/layouts"
    })
  );
  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: Can you include more details about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, hope your issue would be solved:

```
app.engine(
    "hbs",
    expressHbs({
      extname: "hbs",
      defaultLayout: "main-layouts",
      layoutsDir: "views/layouts"
    })
  );
```